# Convert GdkX11Window to VTE Terminal class in an focus event

Tags: gtk, glib, vala, vte

I need to receive a GTK+ focus in event on a Terminal (VTE), but the event returns EventFocus which holds Gtk.Window reference:

http://www.valadoc.org/gdk-3.0/Gdk.EventFocus.html

How can I get the Terminal from the Window reference? I cannot retype it, it looks like it is a container. But I am unable to find which method to call to get the Terminal.

```
  Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
  // ...
  terminal.focus_in_event.connect((event) =>
  {
    the_terminal = event.window; // DOES NOT WORK > invalid cast from `GdkX11Window' to `Terminal'
    return false;
  });
```

Thanks for pointing out I dont need it. Yeah, my real code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < terminal.length; i++) {
  this.terminal[i].focus_in_event.connect((event) =>
  {
    GLib.stdout.printf("Focus event terminal %p\n", this.terminal[i]);
    return false;
  });
}
```

Unfortunately it always prints null :-(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to convert a `Gdk.Window` to a `Gtk.Widget` as not all widgets have an associated GDK window, necessarily. As I see it, there's no compelling reason to try to extract the terminal from the `event`. In the context of the callback, you can simply reference the outer variable `terminal` and Vala will lift it into the callback.

```
Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
// ...
terminal.focus_in_event.connect((event) =>
{
  terminal.queue_draw();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but my problem is I have a bunch (array) of Terminals, so I am connecting in a loop: foreach (Terminal t in terminals). And when I try to use "t" variable there, vala screams. I thought I can use closures, but apparently I cannot.